# Prevent Android from changing the theme

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've set theme `"@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar", but Android keeps switching the way the controls look on different devices.

Is there a way to prevent Android from changing the theme of the application without writing a custom theme?

Comment: Each theme is device dependent unless you customize them. If you want every element/control looking similar on all deices you need to customize them all.

Comment: So you claim, that exact same apk installed on different devices results in applying different themes to app?

Comment: yes. different kind of styles of a same theme to the same app.
for instance on my dev phone it's fine, but it turns out that on some of the user phones it change the styles like the checkboxes goes round or even circular, the colors looks different, etc..